# React Native get element when using querySelector from Web

Tags: react-native, webview, domparser

In React Native i want to parse `www.google.com` and get its element that has a class `class="lnXdpd"`.

I'm unsure how to use `querySelector` so once i fetch the url and have its string to parse it using `querySelector`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetch HTML page file content with Fetch API then parse with HTML Parser.

```js
import { parse } from "node-html-parser";
async function parseURL() {
  try {
    // Smithsonian Museum Homepage
    const response = await fetch("https://www.si.edu/");
    const html = await response.text();

    const parsed = parse(html, {
      blockTextElements: {
        script: false,
        noscript: true,
        style: true,
        pre: true,
      },
    });

    // Find  elements with form-details class
    console.log(parsed.querySelector(".form-details")?.toString());
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}



parseURL()
```

Demo - https://replit.com/@EmmanuelBYIRING/html-parser-url#index.js

Comment: agree i found about this after the i posted